# vite react app unable to publish to github

Tags: reactjs, github-pages, vite

I recently switched from react app to vite app, everything was fine, but until a certain point, I had to push the project to GitHub so that my colleagues could see and evaluate the work I had done, it gives an error in the console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404.

[image: file tree]

I asked other developers, I also tried to get an answer to my question through the telegram groups, but everything that they recommended did not help, after that I, as a real developer, decided to google, I watched various videos, but all this did not help to solve my problem.

Nothing is loading on the site and there is an ordinary white page.

```json
package.json

{
  "name": "upgrade",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "macro-css": "^1.0.5",
    "node-sass": "^9.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.15.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "gh-pages": "^6.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.66.1",
    "vite": "^4.4.5"
  }
}
```

```js
vite.config.js

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  base: "/upgrade/"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

### Remove `/` at end of base properties

```js
vite.config.js

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  base: "/upgrade"
})
```

Adding base: `/upgrade/` to your Vite configuration slightly modifies the base public path of the project. The key difference here is the trailing slash at the end of '/upgrade/'.

**Base Public Path with Trailing Slash:**

When base `/upgrade/`, the application is configured to be served from a path that includes /upgrade/ at its root, with the trailing slash indicating a directory. In practical terms, this usually means that all the relative URLs within your application will be resolved with `/upgrade/` as the base.

For example, if you have an asset linked as `src="assets/image.png"`, it will be resolved as `/upgrade/assets/image.png`.
Similarly, links within your application would also base themselves off this `/upgrade/` path.